# Printing sections of a text file with C

Tags: c

I'm looking for a solution on how to print only relevant sections from a log file where I want to display the code and its contents which spans multiple lines.

The log file is structured like this:

```
----- start -----
CODE: 1111

DESC: this is some descriptions
      which spans multiple lines.
-----  end  -----

----- start -----
CODE: 2222

DESC: this is some information
      for another code.
-----  end  -----

----- start -----
CODE: 1111

DESC: here is some more info
      for the code again.
-----  end  -----
```

What I like to achieve if to parse the log file using C, to generate a result similar
to this.

```
----- start -----
CODE: 1111

DESC: this is some descriptions
      which spans multiple lines.
-----  end  -----

----- start -----
CODE: 1111

DESC: here is some more info
      for the code again.
-----  end  -----
```

I have tried various while loops reading the file into a buffer and compared the strings with strstr() etc. but haven't find any logic with if statements that works for me. I have tried to explore the use of fseek(), fgetpos(), fsetpos() etc. I have searched forums and blogs for answer that can help me forward with little success.

If anyone reading this has a solution to share or any pointer on how I should tackle this, or places to find such information would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please share your code to see what you have tried along with a sample of the raw data so that the community can better analyze your issue.

Comment: Read lines; look for the start marker; check that the next CODE line is what you want (if not, go back to just reading lines).  Print the start marker, the CODE line, and read more lines up to the next end marker.  Go back to reading lines.  Decide where blank lines are added.

Comment: This could easily be solved using AWK: `awk '/^----- start -----$/,/^-----  end  -----$/ { text = text $0 ORS; if($0=="CODE: 1111") found=1 } /^-----  end  -----$/ { if(found) print text; text=""; found=0 }' inputfile`

Comment: Why does `CODE: 2222` not appear in the desired result? Do you want to discard all entries with codes that does not appear in the first log entry?

Comment: This might be a simple [lexer](https://re2c.org/).

Comment: Is your goal to only look for `CODE: 1111`, -- or -- do you want to output all entries where the `CODE: XXXX` appears more than once in a grouped manner? (`awk` provides a simple solution either way) What you need to do will depend on your goal. Searching for one entry (e.g. `CODE: 1111` ) is much easier than generically searching for each set of entries that appear more than once in the log.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I will take all your comments and learn from it. And NoDakker, I have tried so many variations and at best only been able to print out one, the first occurrence it found and had currently just deleted all the mess in that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about the "---start---" to begin with. Just look for the target that means an interesting section is beginning. Then output until the "---end---" is encountered.

Here's a sample that works for the sample input you provided. Just uses `fgets()` until it finds the target string, sets a flag and outputs the preamble (that is given) and loops until it clears the flag. If the current line is neither the start nor the finish, output (or not) is controlled by the flag.

You can adapt this to your particular needs with passing logfile names and target string(s) through command line parameters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char buf[ 1024 ];

    FILE *ifp = fopen( "log.txt", "rt" );
    if( ifp == NULL )
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );

    char *target = "CODE: 1111";
    char *start = "-----  start  -----";
    char *end = "-----  end  -----";
    char *blankrow = "";
    bool inRegion = false;

    while( fgets( buf, sizeof buf, ifp ) ) {
        if( inRegion && strncmp( buf, end, strlen( end ) ) == 0 ) {
            inRegion = false;
            printf( "%s", buf );
        } else if( strncmp( buf, target, strlen( target ) ) == 0 ) {
            inRegion = true;
            printf( "%s%s\n%s", blankrow, start, buf );
            blankrow = "\n";
        } else if( inRegion ) {
            printf( "%s", buf );
        }
    }
    fclose( ifp );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not sure what compiler you are using, but you would need `stdlib.h` (`exit()`) and `stdbool.h` (`bool`). Additionally, never return a negative number from `main()` to the shell.  `stdlib.h` defines `EXIT_SUCCESS` (`0`) and `EXIT_FAILURE` (`1`), all other values are implementation defined but POSIX only allows 8-bit unsigned values. [POSIX return - EXIT STATUS](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/return.html) Returning `-1` is a sign-extended 32-bit integer. (now the world won't end, but you don't want to tempt fate either...)

Comment: Thank you so much Fe2O3! This was very helpful and solved my problem. Also I learned a great deal on how to tackle such problem.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I've read the 'header' to the `[c]` tags and understand SO focusses on current standards. My compiler is from the last century. My hope is to help with algorithm problems like this OP, while I understand that I'm not "up to date" with the latest do's-and-don'ts... Thank you for your corrections to this post.

Comment: No worries, I figured that was the case. I think you have a good solution and if this goal was just to search for the `CODE: 1111` entries, you have it. If the goal was to find all `CODE: XXXX` entries appearing more than once, then that's a different challenge. Wasn't clear from the question, but I suspect it is as you have it. Was waiting on clarification to vote, but may as well. Only other suggestion I would have is don't use "cuddle-up" on the `if` blocks, e.g. `"}\nelse if"` makes it easier for old-eyes to read (I qualify)

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve the problem, you can read until you encounter the line

```
----- start -----
```

then read the next line to see if it contains the code that you are looking for. If it does, then you output the log entry, and if it does not, then you read and ignore the rest of the log entry.

Since the end of the log entry is clearly marked with the line

```
-----  end  -----
```

you can compare every line inside the log entry with that string.

These steps should be repeated until you encounter end-of-file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

const char  start_marker[] = "----- start -----";
const char    end_marker[] = "-----  end  -----";
const char target_string[] = "CODE: 1111";

bool read_exactly_one_line( char buffer[], int buffer_size, FILE *fp );

int main( void )
{
    char line[4096];
    bool should_print;

    //read log entries until end-of-file encountered
    for (;;) //infinite loop, equivalent to "while(1)"
    {
        //read until start marker encountered
        for (;;)
        {
           if ( ! read_exactly_one_line( line, sizeof line, stdin ) ) 
            {
                //we are unable to read any further lines due to
                //end-of-file, so we have finished
                exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );
            }

            //determine whether line is empty
            if ( line[0] == '\0' )
                continue;

            //determine whether line is a start marker
            if ( strcmp( line, start_marker ) == 0 )
                break;

            //line is neither empty nor a start marker, which
            //should not occur
            fprintf( stderr, "Parse error: Unexpected input!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        //read the line with the code
        if ( ! read_exactly_one_line( line, sizeof line, stdin ) )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "Error: Encountered end-of-file inside log entry!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        //determine whether the line contains the target string
        if ( strcmp( line, target_string ) == 0 )
        {
            //we should print the log entry
            should_print = true;

            //also print the part that we have already read
            printf( "%s\n%s\n", start_marker, line );
        }
        else
        {
            //do not print the remainder of the log entry
            should_print = false;
        }

        //read until end marker
        for (;;)
        {
            if ( ! read_exactly_one_line( line, sizeof line, stdin ) )
            {
                fprintf( stderr, "Error: Encountered end-of-file inside log entry!\n" );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }

            //print the line, if appropriate
            if ( should_print )
                printf( "%s\n", line );

            //determine whether line is the end marker
            if ( strcmp( line, end_marker ) == 0 )
            {
                //add one line of spacing between next log entry
                if ( should_print )
                    printf( "\n" );

                //break out of inner infinite loop
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

//This function will read exactly one line and remove the newline
//character, if it exists. On success, it will return true. If this
//function is unable to read any further lines due to end-of-file,
//it returns false. If it fails for any other reason, it will not
//return, but will print an error message and call "exit" instead.
bool read_exactly_one_line( char buffer[], int buffer_size, FILE *fp )
{
    char *p;

    if ( fgets( buffer, buffer_size, fp ) == NULL )
    {
        if ( ferror( fp ) )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "Input error!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        return false;
    }

    //make sure that line was not too long for input buffer
    p = strchr( buffer, '\n' );
    if ( p == NULL )
    {
        //a missing newline character is ok on end of file
        if ( !feof(fp) )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "Line was too long for input buffer!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //remove newline character
        *p = '\0';
    }

    return true;
}
```

With the input posted in the question, this program has the following output:

```
----- start -----
CODE: 1111

DESC: this is some descriptions
      which spans multiple lines.
-----  end  -----

----- start -----
CODE: 1111

DESC: here is some more info
      for the code again.
-----  end  -----
```

Comment: Thank you very much Andreas! I will study this and learn yet another way to solve it :)